# Tag Info not showing

Tags: bug, status-completed

I added a note to Tag Info about 10 minutes ago that went to review because I have insufficient rep in SU. Since then, I earned the Tag Editor badge and got the edit points, however, the Tag Info is still empty. Is this a bug?

See: https://superuser.com/tags/microsoft-access/info

Comment: According to the [revision history](http://superuser.com/posts/243023/revisions) your edit is there, and I've found the suggestion (it's [#135](http://superuser.com/edit-suggestions/135)) and it was approved 10mins after posting - so you *should* have the badge and rep. The potential bug therefore is that the final result is not being displayed.

Comment: @DMA57361 Exactly. :)

Comment: I'm seeing this on some other approved edits as well. Potentially the pattern is that those that do not work are those without an excerpt - I've a feeling that the ecerpt might be required for a tag wiki to be valid.

Comment: @DMA57361 Okay, that seems reasonable, though a warning would be nice. Can you fix it for me or do I need to try again?

Comment: We leave it for now, it needs escalating to the team to fix, but it's already been reported on [meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78032/omitting-excerpt-section-of-tag-wiki-blanks-out-entire-tag-wiki) so should be in hand.

Comment: @DMA57361 Okay, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was approved, however you left the excerpt blank which messes stuff up big time.

I think I should disallow edits to tag wikis that leave the excerpt blank.

Comment: I left out the excerpt deliberately, because it seemed a little silly to repeat the same two lines. In other words, there was nothing to excerpt from and no warning.